# Exception: The volume does not contain a recognized file system

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlstreamreader

I have created a .net 4.5 wpf application which deserializes an xml file. Strangely in one of the deployed workstations we got an:

```
System.IO.IOException: The volume does not contain a recognized file system.
Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted.
```

because it is a settings file only read once the loading of the file is done using a StreamReader with ReadToEnd.

Any idea why this might be happening? Can be that the OS sets off this and thinks that the hdd is corrupted?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but I think this question cannot easily be answered. Without knowing anything about the workstations it's all about speculation. Additionally, I'm not sure, that SO is the right place to ask such a question, but since I don't have an alternative...

Comment: Does this system have any utilities on it that directly manipulate the MBR and/or partition table (e.g., Norton GoBack)?  I understand these types of apps can cause this error to be thrown.